# How can I return a function's argument after the original value has been overwritten?

Tags: r, arguments

I know that R has an easy way to do this, but I've not been able to recall it. Say that I have this terrible code:

```
add2<-function(n)
{
  n<-n+2
  return(paste(n,"added to 2 is",n))
}
```

Obviously, add2(4) will return something silly like "6 added to 2 is 6". I know that R has a way to return the original argument of this function that will give me my intended behavior, i.e. the output "4 added to 2 is 6". But what is it? In other words, what function should replace the first n in my return value?

Note: I don't want a better way of solving this example. The example is a deliberate oversimplification to show what function I'm really after.

Comment: `add2<-function(n)
{
  n2 <-n+2
  return(paste(n,"added to 2 is",n2))
}
add2(10)` ?

Comment: @user63230 That's specifically what my note at the end was trying rule out. My memory insists that R has a specific **function** for recalling arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case there is no need to override `n` at all. The following code does exactly the same:

```
add2 <- function (n) {
  paste(n, "added to 2 is", n + 2)
}
```

And the function name `add2` is misleading since it implies that the function’s result is, indeed, `n + 2` rather than some message *about* that computation.

More generally, you rarely want to *overwrite* values. It’s almost always more appropriate to create a new variable to hold the result of a computation:

```
add2 <- function (n) {
  result <- n + 2
  message(paste(n, "added to 2 is", result))
  result
}
```

This will

1. compute the result,
2. print a diagnostic message,
3. return the computed result.

Is that what you’re after?

To be more literal, the following works in *a few* cases (but not in general):

```
add2 <- function (n) {
    n <- n + 2
    paste(match.call()$n, "added to 2 is", n)
}
```

And here’s how this fails:

```
add2(1 + 2)
# [1] "+ added to 2 is 5" "1 added to 2 is 5" "2 added to 2 is 5"
```

… and it’s an abuse of `match.call`.

Comment: ```match.call``` is probably what I'm after. I'll have to check up on why that's an abuse. I was under the impression that this was idiomatic for packages.

Comment: @J.Mini I’ve never seen this usage, and I can’t think of a case where this would even make sense! And, importantly, as noted this won’t always work. In particular, it will fail when the argument that was passed into the function is not a simple literal. And a “fixed” solution will fail if the argument has a side-effect, because it will re-evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion in the comments, is `match.call` what you're after?

```
add2<-function(n)
{
  x <- match.call()
  n<-n+2
  print(x)
  print(names(x))
  print(x$n)
  return(paste(n,"added to 2 is",n))
}
add2(4)
add2(n = 4)
[1] ""  "n"
[1] 4
[1] "6 added to 2 is 6"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
add2<-function(n)
{
  n1<-n+2
  return(paste(n,"added to 2 is",n1))
}

add2(4)
[1] "4 added to 2 is 6"
```

Comment: That's specifically what my note at the end was trying rule out. My memory insists that R has a specific **function** for recalling arguments.

Comment: @J.Mini It doesn’t, and (as explained in my answer) such a function wouldn’t be helpful in idiomatic R.